# In Selenium TestNG , I want to execute same testcase concurrently in multiple sessions . What attributes should i add in xml?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

In Selenium TestNG , I want to execute same testcase concurrently in multiple sessions . What attributes should i add in XML?

1 TestCase --> 10 concurrent sessions --> same time

Comment: is it a simple 10mins test or big one ?

Comment: Why do you want to run same TC in concurrent session ?